# Android Studio 0.8.2 changes my input of Watch from is to this

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am debugging app with Android Studio 0.8.2.

I want to add `is` variable (of InputStream type) for watching but Android Studio changes it to `this`.
In affect I cannot see `is` value

How could I overcome this bug?

Comment: Cheap shot but give this a try: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import; in the Exclude from Import and Completion box add "this" (no quotes).

Comment: Also update AS to 0.8.9